# Read multiple bib for bibliometrix

Tags: r

I have downloaded different bibtext files from scopus.

I would like to combine them into a single vector like the example in bibliometrix package:

```
library(bibliometrix)
D <- readFiles("http://www.bibliometrix.org/datasets/savedrecs.bib")
```

I tried this option:

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/bibtexscopus", pattern="*.bib", full.names=TRUE)
df <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread), fill = TRUE)
```

but the rbindlist creates many columns. How can a read multiple bib files into a single vector like the example of bibliometrix?

Answer (score 1):

D <- c("file1.bib","file2.bib","file3.bib")

You can also use relative file paths if using, eg, RStudio projects.

D <- c("./data/file1.bib","./data/file2.bib","./data/file3.bib")